# Does anyone know why the tapped event of the uwp slider doesn't work often?

Tags: c#, events, uwp, slider

I have a blank uwp app, and I'm testing Slider events, I noticed that Tapped event of Slider doesn't work often. Does anyone know what's a problem?

```
<Page
x:Class="App1.MainPage"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}"
mc:Ignorable="d">

<Grid>
    <Slider x:Name="slider"/>
</Grid>
```

```
public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
    {
        public MainPage()
        {
            this.InitializeComponent();
            slider.Tapped += Slider_Tapped;
        }
        private void Slider_Tapped(object sender, TappedRoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            
        }
    }
```

I am tried tapped on slider and often the event listener doesn't hear it․
Here is project.
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1_2qcA2SccdsZmE_biwcA8-Z7G91r97JB/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Maybe you move slightly while tapping and a different event like manipulation oder sliderMove is fired?

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but the problem was something else, the answer is below․

Answer (score 0):

The tapped event doesn't fire when the track rectangle is tapped.

[image]

It can be seen from the source code that this Slider track is composed of Rectangle controls.

```
<Rectangle x:Name="HorizontalTrackRect" Grid.ColumnSpan="3" Fill="{TemplateBinding Background}" Height="{ThemeResource SliderTrackThemeHeight}" Grid.Row="1"/>
<Rectangle x:Name="HorizontalDecreaseRect" Fill="{TemplateBinding Foreground}" Grid.Row="1"/>
```

The ValueChanged event is triggered when the track rectangle is tapped, and the Slider control won't handle the tapped event at this time.